# What's the difference between D&D 3.5 and D&D 3.5E?

Tags: dnd-3.5e

What is the difference between D&D 3.5 and D&D 3.5E? 
If there is one.

Answer (score 17):

"D&D 3.5" and "D&D 3.5E" are the same thing: the "E" is something fans use to mean "Edition". It could be mistaken for a revision letter (as in Revision A, Revision B, ... Revision E), but it's not.

The official name of the game is "*Dungeons & Dragons v3.5*". It followed "*Dungeons & Dragons* 3rd edition", which was often abbreviated "D&D 3e". When the revised v3.5 edition was released, fans had to figure out how to abbreviate it and two ways became common, which is why both "D&D 3.5" and "D&D 3.5e" are used today.